# SQLite linked server on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sqlite

I've a SqLite linked server on SQL Server 2008.

I need to import an image column from SQL Server into my SQLite database.

Is that possible?

If yes in what kind of SQLite column to I need?

I need to transform ..... I think

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

From: [here](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

> - NULL. The value is a NULL value.
> - INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8    bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.
> - REAL. The value is a floating point value, stored as an 8-byte IEEE      floating point number.
> - TEXT. The value is a text string, stored using the database encoding     (UTF-8, UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE).
> - BLOB. The value is a blob of data, stored exactly as it was input.

and, from: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

> **image:** Variable-length binary data from 0 through 2^31-1
>   (2,147,483,647) bytes.

I suppose that BLOB should be your needed type

edit:

by the way be careful with the "image" type:

> **Important**
>
> ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of MicrosoftSQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Image column equivalent in SQLite would be `BLOB`.

You can accomplish your import task by writing script which connects to both SQL Server and SQLite database, then reads data from one and inserts it into another.

When you insert your data, be sure to use prepared statements and bind variables with proper data type. For example, if using Perl, use `SQL_BLOB` binding:

```
use DBI qw(:sql_types);
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:my.db");
my $blob = `cat foo.jpg`; # you should read it from SQL Server here
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (?)");
$sth->bind_param(1, $blob, SQL_BLOB);
$sth->execute();
```